# Reset zooming in (pinch) android tablet browser (google chrome) using javascript, html

Tags: html, google-chrome, resize, zooming, tablet

On a html page opened with google chrome on android tablet, i need to catch
that user has done some zoom in (pinch in) and reset it to default after some seconds. (zoom out to default screen size. but i do not want totally prevent zooming, i want allow it, but after some time i want to reset zooming automatically).

catching that user has done some zoom is ok, we can check the screenheight, screenwidth by

```
function getScreenHeight() {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        return window.innerHeight;
    } else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
        && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined'
        && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
        return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else {
       return document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
    }
}
```

But to reset it to default, i tried the following code, which works in ipad (safari) but nothing happens on android tablet (google chrome)

```
function _resetResize() {
    var viewport = document.getElementById('ViewPort');

    viewport.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-  scale=1.0';
    setTimeout(function() {
        viewport.content = '';
    },10);
}
```

Comment: The code above works for the default browser of tablet (same as ipad), but google chrome fails when resetting to default size. I need a solution for google chrome.

Comment: Go to settings panel of google chrome, select accessibility tab, disable the checkbox (force zoom)

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings panel of google chrome, select accessibility tab, disable the checkbox (force zoom)